# Find Java class in .jar using JNI

Tags: java, c++, jar, java-native-interface

I'm writing a program where I call Java functions from C++ code using JNI. My program runs fine if I use `.class` file directly, but when I add it to a jar file `FindClass` fails. For example this works fine

```
    std::string stdOpt = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_jar>/dependency.jar;<path_to_class>";

    boost::scoped_array<char> opt(new char[stdOpt.size() + 1]);
    std::copy(stdOpt.begin(), stdOpt.end(), opt.get());
    opt[stdOpt.size()] = '\0';
    options[0].optionString = opt.get();

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    long status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&m_pJavaVirtualMachine, (void**)&m_pJavaEnvironment, &vm_args);
    if (status != JNI_OK)
        throw std::logic_error("Cannot start Java Virtual Machine");

    m_class = m_pJavaEnvironment->FindClass("MyClass");
    if(m_class == 0)
        throw std::logic_error("Cannot find Java class");
```

But this one fails

```
    std::string stdOpt = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_jar>/dependency.jar;<path_to_jar>/myjar.jar";

    boost::scoped_array<char> opt(new char[stdOpt.size() + 1]);
    std::copy(stdOpt.begin(), stdOpt.end(), opt.get());
    opt[stdOpt.size()] = '\0';
    options[0].optionString = opt.get();

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    long status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&m_pJavaVirtualMachine, (void**)&m_pJavaEnvironment, &vm_args);
    if (status != JNI_OK)
        throw std::logic_error("Cannot start Java Virtual Machine");

    m_class = m_pJavaEnvironment->FindClass("MyClass");    //m_class=NULL
    if(m_class == 0)
        throw std::logic_error("Cannot find Java class");  //throwing exception
```

Is there any difference that I should do when I'm trying to get Java class from `.jar`? What's Wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you try to find a class from `dependency.jar`? Is `FindClass()` successful?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it successfully finds a class.

Comment: In that case please add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can run and test locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, that problem was not in code. Code is fine. Problem was in making `.jar` file. I'm using Visual Studio and for auto compilation `.java` to `.class` and addition `.class` to a `.jar` file I've added to pre-build events to project. So before making `.jar` file I should specify current directory like this

> cd "<_directory_where_.class_file_is_located>"
>
> jar cf myjar.jar MyClass.class

Otherwise `MyClass.class` was added to `.jar` file with folders of it's absolute path and `FindClass()` failed.

Answer (score 5):

If your class is in a package, include the package in the call to FindClass, not the class path.

```
 m_class = m_pJavaEnvironment->FindClass( "com/mycompany/mypackage/MyClass" );
```

Comment: I know that, but my class is not in any package.

Comment: If you haven't specified a package, then it's in an unnamed package. IIRC, unnamed packages have a few oddities. One thing I would try is putting it in a package, and seeing if that makes a difference. Having a named package is useful anyway, to avoid nameclash.